# When i try to fetch data in my React project, then I get this error: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I want to get filtered data from MongoDb using a specific email in my react project. So, I create an HTTP request using an email and then try to use the data, then I get the following error:

> GET http://localhost:5000/bloodRequest/amin@gmail.com 404 (Not Found)
> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at
> position 0

My client-side requesting code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/bloodRequest/amin@gmail.com`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setRequests(data));   }, [requests]);
```

My server-side code:

```
  app.get("/donateBlood/:email", async (req, res) => {
      const email = req.params.email;
      const query = { email: email };
      const cursor = donateBloodsCollection.find(query);
      const result = await cursor.toArray();
      res.json(result);
    });
```

**But when I change the HTTP request syntax and use the email in the middle of the HTTP link, it works fine.**
example:

Client-side code:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/amin@gmail.com/bloodRequest`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setRequests(data));   }, [requests]);
```

server-side code:

```
app.get("/:email/donateBlood", async (req, res) => {
      const email = req.params.email;
      const query = { email: email };
      const cursor = donateBloodsCollection.find(query);
      const users = await cursor.toArray();
      res.json(users);
    });
```

In that case, it works properly, I don't know why? Can you explain, please?

Comment: `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`  usually means that the endpoint is returning HTML. Maybe it's a 4XX or 5XX error?

Comment: _"Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"_ usually means that's **not** JSON, it's e.g. XML or more often HTML. Did you look at what the actual response body was? Note you should really URL-encode that `@`, to `%40`.

Comment: did you try to get a response using Postman first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fetch call is calling a URL `/bloodRequest/amin@gmail.com`, the corresponding server API definition has `/donateBlood/:email`, so the 404 error you have got is expected.

> GET http://localhost:5000/bloodRequest/amin@gmail.com 404 (Not Found)
> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at
> position 0

Try either changing the client-side URL to `/donateBlood/amin@gmail.com` or server-side API to `/bloodRequest/:email`.

PS: Basically, the code you are trying is syntactically valid. It must have been failed due to typos in the URL or not restarting the server after a particular change. I can see the same URL mismatch in the working code you have posted, so it should also have thrown 404. Please post the exact code you have tried if it doesn't work yet.